# How to complete an entity with relations which cannot be mapped by doctrine

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity `person`, which is linked to an `person_groups` table.
As this link is not done through `person.id` primary key, but through an index `person.matricule`, I cannot map this attribute with a many to one relation
However, I'd really like to have a `groups` property in my entity. How can this be achieved ?

I was thinking of using the doctrine event lifecycle, to dynamically update my entity at load time. Is it a good idea ? Are there other solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason you can't map it by doctrine?

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="YourNamespace\YourEntityGroups",
 *     mappedBy="person"
 * )
 */
protected $groups;
```

and

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *     targetEntity="YourNamespace\YourEntityPerson",
 *     inversedBy="groups"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_matricule", referencedColumnName="matricule")
 */
protected $person;
```

Comment: Because doctrine can join only on primary key: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html